# Using javascript to link after checking terms and conditions are checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to make a link that goes to paypal, but the link will only work if a checkbox has been checked. This is my code:

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MDSGURBJXF5K6" onclick="return buy_link(this)">Buy hard copy</a>
```

Javascript

```
function buy_link(link){
  agree_check = oForm.elements["agree"].value;
  if(agree_check === true){
   window.location = link.href;
  }else{
   alert("You must agree to the terms and conditions before purchasing.");
  }
  return false;
}
```

It seems to just link whatever happens? event if I comment out the window.location() function. Any idea's where I am going wrong?

Comment: I thing you should inspect the `checked` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the link to `buy_link()`. If the `onClick` event handler returns false,  the browser won't further process the event, and the href won't be used. If it returns true, it will.

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=MDSGURBJXF5K6" onclick="return buy_link();">Buy hard copy</a>


function buy_link(){
    agree_check = oForm.elements["agree"].checked;
    if(!agree_check){
      alert("You must agree to the terms and conditions before purchasing.");
    }
    return agree_check;
  }
```

Comment: [Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/220299/paul-creasey)'s response is addressing the point here. The `checked` property is the one to look at. Also fixed it in this answer.

Comment: Ok what you say makes sence, but for some reason I am still getting the same problem? This is the checkbox[code]<input type="checkbox" id="agree">[/code]

Comment: Do you have javascript enabled? This solution is js-dependent, you can't handle `onclick` without javascript. Also check that oForm.elements["agree"] is actually an element. Alternatively, you could do `agree_check=document.getElementById('checkId').checked` with `<input type='checkbox' id='checkId'>`

Comment: Thank you very much this worked :) I feel stupid now, but it was blatently because the input box isnt actualy in a form atall

Answer (score 0):

```
var agree_check = Form.elements["agree"].checked;
```

or just

```
if (Form.elements["agree"].checked)
{
```

Xavi López is correct about not passing the link to the function.